# Retrive records from a table when all rows are good

Tags: oracle

I have a table like this

| Category | business_date | load_date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11/1/20 | 12/1/20 | Good |
| B | 11/1/20 | 12/1/20 | Good |
| C | 11/1/20 | 12/1/20 | Inprogress |

I need to retrieve rows when only all the status values are `good`, if there is `inprogress` should not retrieve any row

Expected output:

1 row as below

| Status | business_date | load_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Good | 11/1/20 | 12/1/20 |

Comment: Please, show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it. Simple `where` should be sufficient, but you say not, and the reason is not clear

Comment: What is the business meaning of having the result set without the Category column?  And related, why does your desired result set not have a row for Category 'A' and for Category 'B'?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data with the status is Good, the query is:

```
SELECT status, business_date, load_date FROM yourTable WHERE status ='Good';
```

But, if want to avoid duplicated values, your query becomes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT status, business_date, load_date FROM yourTable WHERE status ='Good';
```

Comment: This is not what I am expecting , with above I will get 2 records , if the status column  rows are all good then print data or else don't print i.e retrive data (if there is any value apart from good it should not retrive data )

Comment: Your problem seems to be more complicated than the displayed data in your example.
But, if you want to extract a single status='Good' for identical couple (business_date, load_date). You will have to use the DISTINCT clause. I corrected my answer to take this case into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT Category,
       business_date,
       load_date,
       status
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN status != 'Good' THEN 1 END) OVER () AS num_not_good
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  num_not_good = 0;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Category, business_date, load_date, status) AS
SELECT 'A', DATE '2020-01-11', DATE '2020-01-12', 'Good' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2020-01-11', DATE '2020-01-12', 'Good' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', DATE '2020-01-11', DATE '2020-01-12', 'Inprogress' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs, as expected, no rows as there is an `Inprogress` row.

If you then use:

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET status = 'Good';
```

Then run the query again then the output is:

> | CATEGORY | BUSINESS_DATE | LOAD_DATE | STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 11-JAN-20 | 12-JAN-20 | Good |
> | B | 11-JAN-20 | 12-JAN-20 | Good |
> | C | 11-JAN-20 | 12-JAN-20 | Good |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3bacafc43aa66b4eb10847e41fa15528)*